# How to design basic skeleton of java for testing of tab separated text file containing 1 lakh record

Tags: java, parsing, csv

i have a text file which contains 100000 line as below

```
be3c152f6f6bcd5 AL9 60  51.7458349055774    -0.191050898942398  F

be3c15cd5   AL9 30  51.79055774 -0.191050898942398  M
```

now i have to create a design where i need to read all this and based on test condition
needs to generate the output in same file format which i read

i was thinking this to implement by

1. reading all lines of input file
2. keeping them in `List<some pojo>`

now this pojo will have reference to all condition and generate the o\p

my question is loop readline 1 l00000 times and generate the pojo is good or not ?Also in the final  o\p folder for each test case condition i have to convert this `List<pojo` to text format as above what we read.

please let me know some better way.

Comment: Lakh is not a SI unit... It is good to keep in mind what others know, if you'd like to get help... [(It actually means 100000.)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh)

Comment: Sorry not making myself clear.. the total data is 100000 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple problem for parsing records.

You don't want each line in a `List`; you want the POJO containing the data after you tokenize each line.

Here's pseudo-code:

1. Open file
2. Loop over all lines in file
3. Tokenize each line and populate POJO
4. Add POJO to List
5. Close file
6. Perform any operations you wish on POJOs
7. Output POJO List in desired format

If it's just tab delimited, perhaps you can use a library that already deals with .csv files.

Comment: i was just thinking keeping threshold limit of total line as 100000 that i have to two process first 1. read text file containing total data and for each line populate the pojo and add to List .. will it be heavy operation 2. in the last say i processed one test condition then we need to output again the list of updated data to new text file which i read earlier will it be kind of performance .. i am just scared containing 100000 pojo in List is it overhead ?

Comment: also can you suggest me some utilities which will convert List<Pojo> TO text file format ?

Comment: Are you incapable of searching SO or Google?  C'mon, man: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410538/which-is-the-best-csv-parser-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Read line, process line, write line. No need to keep them all in memory.

Comment: thanks but in this way all the times for all condition we need to read all 100000 lines and process for output file .. so this will be not kind of generic i have 100+ cases for which i have to work like this, thats why i was thinking to generate a kind of data structure and then process and keep them in memory.. but i am also afraid keeping huge data in memory may create another issue please correct me . thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume, the test conditions only depend on one line at a time:

You should stream the data both in and out. 
After processing the first line - which consists of reading and parsing - check the conditions. If the line should be kept in the output, you can now stream it to the (different) output file. If it should be deleted, you can just ignore it and skip to the next line of the input.

It sounds like a good idea to create an Element which has the different columns of the file as fields. You could then overwrite to String to generate the desired output and a Constructor which takes the String in the input Format to parse it.